# Xamarin Forms Realm

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm

I am trying to add Realm to my project, I've installed it but when I try to run the project even with no single line added it gives me this error in the android project: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you run your project **immediately** prior to installing Realm, with no other changes?

It seems highly unlikely that this is caused by Realm.

When you say *installed* I assume you mean via NuGet. Did you update your other NuGet packages at the same time?

As a general tip for everyone, use version control and save a version somehow immediately before you add any package via an installer, just in case something goes wrong.

I work on the Realm Xamarin team and, whilst we have had occasional NuGet issues, this is the first time anything like this has shown up, which is why I suspect it is a side-effect of other updates at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for your advice. I have a problem with controlling versions of NuGet packages, in every new project it ask me to update 6 packages: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompact, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.cardview, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter and xamarin.forms. Once I update all it gives me this error: Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 23.4.0.1' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.2.127 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)'. So I don't update it

Comment: Please try taking Realm OUT of your project using NuGet and see if the project compiles. Also, as a general tip, I regularly have to delete all 'bin' and 'obj' folders to make Xamarin Studio happy.